# knockout 2.0 doesn't work in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

This view works well with IE9 and Chrome. However, not with IE8.
When the page is rendered, this is how it looks like:

[image]

My HTML (MVC3 View) is as shown below.

```
<div id="machinedisplay" data-bind="with: selectedMachine" >
<h2><span data-bind="text: MachineDesciption" /></h2>
<!-- ko with: my.vm.machineData -->
<table>
    <thead><tr>
               <th>Point Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Points Data</th>
           </tr></thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Points">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: PointName()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: PointDesciption()"></td>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <thead><tr>
                               <th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Value</th><th></th>
                           </tr></thead>

                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Params">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: ParameterName"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: ParameterDescription"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: StringValue"></td>
                        </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>            
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Any ideas on IE8 work around?

**EDIT:**
To illustrate this problem on a simpler model, check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ericpanorel/nzKvb/

I figured that I am running into problems because I am using the "with" or "if" bindings. I read somewhere that this causes problems with IE8.

I used IE9, and if you use your developer tools to switch from IE9 to IE8, this Fiddle doesn't work properly anymore. This fiddle is actually derived from one of knockout's samples (http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)

**EDIT:**
I updated the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/nzKvb/20/
It has something to do with short-hand closing of tags inside the nested containerless bindings

```
 <!-- ko if: Allowed-->
<h2>
 <span data-bind="text: Dummy"/>     <===== This will bomb in IE8 
</h2>
```

Comment: Not sure what the significance of the screenshot is? So the contents of the div machinedisplay is blank? Can you provide your javascript?

Comment: "It has something to do with short-hand closing of tags inside the nested containerless bindings" - so can't you just not do that? Just add the separate closing </span> tag. I've used with and if binding in IE8 with no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jsFiddle had an extra comma at the end of the array, which IE8 was treating as a null object:

```
var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    { name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"},
    { name: "HK 416", price: "2420.00"}, <-- HERE !!!
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The fiddle works fine without the comma:

http://jsfiddle.net/XPMUA/

Not sure if this solves your underlying problem but at least the fiddle is working now :-)

Comment: YIkes, oh well. Yeah, still doesn't solve my problem. I thought I found a good sample.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here because

```
<!-- ko if: Allowed-->
```

> Older IE versions can be picky about using JavaScript reserved words
>   for property names.

So you should write `'if'`

Check [Same problem in another link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141205/1461421)!

Comment: And how is that a problem? Care to explain?

Comment: I'm not sure about the 'if' example, but I know that IE8 does break if you don't quote certain reserved words. data-bind="attr: { class: whatever }" in this instance, class needs to be 'quoted'.