# Using conditional knockout templates with IE8

Tags: templates, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, knockout.js

In all 'modern' browsers the following works **but not in IE8:**

```
<!-- ko template: {if: $root.itemToEdit.SomeObject() === $data, name: 'EditItemTemplate', afterRender: $root.initializeEditPanel } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5022: Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: Expected
>   identifier, string or number; Bindings value: template: {if:
>   $root.itemToEdit.SomeObject() === $data, name: 'EditItemTemplate',
>   afterRender: $root.initializeEditPanel }

It seems to be the inclusion of the `if` statement inside the template definition. If I change the markup to the following, IE8 is happy:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.itemToEdit.SomeObject() === $data -->
   <!-- ko template: {name: 'EditItemTemplate', afterRender: $root.initializeEditPanel } -->
   <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Why does including an `if` statement in my template not work in IE8?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Older IE versions can be picky about using JavaScript reserved words for property names.  If you specify the `if` like `'if'`, then you will be fine.  Like:

```
<!-- ko template: {'if': $root.itemToEdit.SomeObject() === $data, name: 'EditItemTemplate', afterRender: $root.initializeEditPanel } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or something like `<label data-bind="attr : { 'for': id }"></label>`

Comment: I might post this as Q&A here, but for now, only because I just spent 5 hours trying to figure this out... if you are having issues with IE8 and KO templates, make sure your actual template isn't inside any ko if blocks.  I had my templates in various parts of the page and was having problems in IE8 only.  Moved them all to the top of the body, now working great.

Comment: @eselk You saved me at least 5 hours just by writing your comment. Thank you!

Comment: holy @#$! there's no reason that this should fix the odd memory leaks we were seeing come out of IE8...most useful bit of nonsense I've read in terms of KO fixes...and for it to be only with 'if' in templates...geez.

Comment: oh...and thank you. thank you for finding this obscure solution to an otherwise maddening 'bug'.

Comment: Also does not like the keyword ***class***, as with the ***if*** must use it in quotes.

Comment: I also saw this error popup from malformed HTML that did not cause problems in other browsers.  An extra "/>" after an element was causing it.

Comment: Same thing here with keyword 'for': data-bind="attr: { for: UID }"